# Powershell set-content adding hidden characters

Tags: powershell

Following scenario:

```
Set-Content $healthStatusFileName "a 'r'n a"  
$previousHealthStatus=$(Get-Content $healthStatusFileName )  
$errorMessage = "a 'r'n a" 


If ($previousHealthStatus -eq $errorMessage)
```

Now for some reason the if statement always returns false, why? It only happens when having the carriage return line feed in the string.
Also, doing this before the If does not help:

```
$previousHealthStatus = $previousHealthStatus -replace "'t|'n|'r",""
$errorMessage = $errorMessage -replace "'t|'n|'r",""
```

Comment: You know the special character indicator is backtick (`\``) and not single quote (`'`), right?

Comment: yeah I used backtick in the code, but when typing that here it doesn't get dispalyed, not sure how to escape it.

Comment: Ah, it's used as the inline code format markdown character.  Inline, put a backspace before it.  For block code, you just put four spaces at the beginning of the line and it should treat the whole like as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-Content returns an array, so you are comparing a string with an array. Join the array with

```
`r`n
```

so you get the equivalent of your initial string.

```
Set-Content $healthStatusFileName "a `r`n a"  
$previousHealthStatus=$(Get-Content $healthStatusFileName ) -join "`r`n"
$errorMessage = "a `r`n a" 
($previousHealthStatus -eq $errorMessage)
```

result is:

```
True
```

Comment: If you're using PowerShell 3.0, you can try `Get-Content $healthStatusFileName -Raw`.  That should read the file as a single string including line breaks.  Alternately, you can try `Get-Content $healthStatusFileName | Out-String` which works on all versions.

Comment: Awesome that's it, I actually wasted a lot of time on this issue.